# Creating instance from two interface implementations

Tags: c++, interface, instance

What i want is to have an object with some methods that are implemented in specific way, and other implemented different. I decided to use two interfaces.
Let's call it `InterfaceA` and `InterfaceB`. Both interfaces, can have various implementations. Let me show code:

```
class InterfaceA
{
  public:
    virtual int method_A_foo(void) = 0;
    virtual int method_A_bar(void) = 0;
};

class InterfaceB
{
  public:
    virtual int method_B_foo(void) = 0;
    virtual int method_B_bar(void) = 0;
};
```

Now i have several implementations of `InterfaceA`, let say i have `IA_instance1`, `IA_instance2`. That implementations are base for `InterfaceB` which uses methods from `InterfaceA`, implementations:

```
class IA_instance1 : public InterfaceA
{
  public:
    int method_A_foo(void);
    int method_A_bar(void);
};

class IA_instance2 : public InterfaceA
{
  public:
    int method_A_foo(void);
    int method_A_bar(void);
};

class IB_instance : public InterfaceB
{
  public:

    /* in implementation of this method i want to call method_A_foo() twice */
    int method_B_foo(void);

    /* in implementation of this method i want to call method_A_foo() 4 times and method_A_bar() one time*/
    int method_B_bar(void);
};
```

What i have done is that i created an abstract class that wraps both interfaces. `InterfaceA` implementation is present in this abstract class, and `InterfaceB` implementation is moved to derived class:

```
class InterfaceBase : public InterfaceA, InterfaceB
{
  private:
    InterfaceA * m_interfaceA;

  public:
    InterfaceBase(InterfaceA * _interfaceA)
    {
      this->m_interfaceA = _interfaceA;
    }

    int method_A_foo(void)
    {
      return this->m_interfaceA->method_A_foo();
    }

    int method_A_bar(void)
    {
      return this->m_interfaceA->method_A_bar();
    }

    virtual int method_B_foo(void) = 0;
    virtual int method_B_bar(void) = 0;
};


class IB_instance1 : public InterfaceBase
{
  public:
    IB_instance1(InterfaceA * _interafceA)
      : InterfaceBase(_interafceA)
    { }

    int method_B_foo(void);
    int method_B_bar(void);
};
```

Now what i need is to have implementation of `InterfaceA`, and pass it into constructor to `IB_instance1`. I don't create class which implements both interfaces and thus i don't duplicate `InterfaceA` implementations. I use one instance of `InterfaceA` and i pass it to `InterfaceBase` wrapper. I could do following:

```
InterfaceA * instanceA1 = new IA_instance1();
InterfaceBase * instanceB1 = new IB_instance1(instanceA1);
```

I have following questions:

- Is it good idea to solve this problem in such way? Can i do it better?
- Need i to duplicate `virtual int` declarations in `InterfaceBase`? If i remove them i won't be able to call `InterfaceB` methods after cast to `InterfaceBase *`. I am able to call `InterfaceA` methods but for `InterfaceB` i have to put `virtual int` declarations in `InterfaceBase`

However, for me this seems to be good way, i think writing declarations and definitions and use separate .h and .cpp files are horrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Need I to duplicate virtual int declarations in `InterfaceBase` ? If I remove them I won't be able to call `InterfaceB` methods after cast to `InterfaceBase *`. I am able to call `InterfaceA` methods but for `InterfaceB` I have to put virtual int declarations in `InterfaceBase`.

It is due to the fact that you **privately** inherit from `InterfaceB` instead of publicly. Change your code to

```
class InterfaceBase : public InterfaceA, public InterfaceB
{
    /* Your implementation without repeating InterfaceB */
};
```

Comment: well, i didn't noticed i flattened InterfaceB. I thought only one [public/private/protected] should be after colon, now i see i was wrong. It works.